# Вареный и сваренный? В чем разница по смыслу, когда употреблять?

Tags: смысл

Вареный и сваренный? В чем разница по смыслу, когда употреблять?
Мы обычно говорим вареная колбаса, а не сваренная. Хотя она сварена.

Comment: Ещё такой момент: "варёная колбаса" (название еды), но "сваренная вчера колбаса" (есть зависимое слово).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Варёный" употребляется в названии продуктов, блюд, как и "жареный" (ср.: "пожаренный"), "копчёный" (ср.: "закопчённый") и т.д. Это отглагольные прилагательные, поэтому одна Н. Здесь качество, а не действие.
"Варёный" обычно находится рядом с существительным.

"Сваренный" — этот тот, который сварили. Причастие совершенного вида (доварили, а не лишь начали), акцент на действии.
В этих примерах "варёный" не подходит:
*Сваренный в кожуре картофель самый полезный.

Борщ, сваренный накануне, стал еще вкуснее.*
Удачно употреблять с действующим лицом:
*Суп, сваренный шеф-поваром.*

Ещё есть "[в**а**ренный](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)" — когда варили, но так и не сварили.